# UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend and screen refresh

Tags: ios, background, sleep, exit

I have an app that has the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend info list property set to TRUE.
And now I am noticing a curious issue.
I start up the app and let it run on my phone and do not touch my phone. Eventually the phone screen goes dark and the phone goes into standby mode. When I wake the phone up, what I see is a screenshot of the last screen displayed on the app. (This seems according to spec, since the Apple documentation says that in the process of moving an app to the background, ios takes a picture of the app and uses that for transitions when the app comes back to life). If I double click on the home button to see running apps, I do not see an instance of the app running. (again, working as intended since UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend is set to true).

My question is, how do I make sure that when the phone wakes up, it comes back to the default home screen and not the picture of the app ? Clearly the app is not running on waking up, so there is nothing I can do from within the app that will refresh the screen. I could try to exit when the app is going to background, but then apple guidelines say, never exit programatically!!.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand what is happening. If you enable `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`, this means your app will terminate when normally the app would go to the background. If you run your app then let the phone sit idle until the screen goes dark, your app is still in the foreground so it is not terminated. When a device goes into standby mode, the current app is still the current app. When you wake the device, you are not looking at snapshot of your app, you are looking at your running app. Double-tapping the Home button at this point doesn't show your app because your app is the currently running app.

Your app will be terminated if you return to the home screen or switch to another app. But it will not terminate just because the device went into standby mode.

If you want your app to return to its main screen when the device is woken up, then you need to put code in the `UIApplicationDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:` method to reset your user interface.